# How to find deteminant of the tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given the matrix:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0  & 0 \\
n - 1 & x & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & n - 2 & x & 3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\          
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x & n - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x
\end{pmatrix} $$

How to find the determinant of $A$. I considered examples for $n = 3,4,5,6$ and obtained some expressions. But I can't understand what the expression for the general case.

I guess that the formula is like the following:
$$ \det(A) = x^n - x^{n-2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}( i \cdot (n - i) ) + ...  $$

Comment: There is a linear recurrence of order $2$ for the determinant of a *general* tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: @Bernard $A_n = x A_{n - 1} + (n - 1) A_{n - 2} $ ?

Comment: $-$, not $+$, as far as I remember.

Comment: @Bernard $A_k = x A_{k - 1} - (k - 1) (n - k + 1) A_{k - 2} $ ?

Comment: I would say so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* The matrix in question is in the form of $xI+K$, where $K$ is a *Kac matrix* [whose spectrum has a closed-form formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340594/calculating-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix).