# How to evaluate this three diagonal determinant?2019

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can someone give me a hint how to solve
\begin{align*}
|A|=\begin{vmatrix} x & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ n-1 & x & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & n-2 & x & 3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & n-3 & x & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x \\ \end{vmatrix}？
\end{align*}

By adding to row 1 the rows from 2 to n ,I can see that $|A|$ has $x+n-1$ as a factor. And by trying $n=2,3,4$, I can deduce that
$$|A|=(x^2-(n-1)^2)(x^2-(n-3)^2)\cdots (x^2-1^2)$$
if $n$ is even, and
$$|A|=(x^2-(n-1)^2)(x^2-(n-3)^2)\cdots (x^2-2^2)x$$
if $n$ is odd. I tried hard to give a proof, but without any progress.

Comment: Note that it would suffice to show that the determinant of $A$ is $0$ when $x = \pm (n-1), \pm (n-3), \pm (n-5),\dots$. I'm not sure how you would go about showing that though.

Comment: This is the characteristic polynomial of a Kac matrix. You may see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/340594) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $|A|=D_n(x)$. By adding the rows numbered $2, 3, \ldots, n$ to row $1$, we get 
\begin{align*}
D_n(x)=
\begin{vmatrix} 
x+n-1 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & \cdots & x+n-1 & x+n-1 \\
 n-1 & x & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & n-2 & x & 3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & n-3 & x & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x 
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
Subsequently we add the rows numbered $3, 4, \ldots, n$ to row $2$, and obtain
\begin{align*}
D_n(x)=
\begin{vmatrix} 
x+n-1 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & \cdots & x+n-1 & x+n-1 \\
 n-1 & x+n-2 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & \cdots &x+n-1 & x+n-1 \\ 
 0 & n-2 & x & 3 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & n-3 & x & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x 
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
$\cdots$ and so on, by  adding the rows numbered $k+1, k+2, \ldots, n$ to row $k$ ($k=1,2,\cdots,n-1$) successively, we finally get
\begin{align*}
D_n(x)=
\begin{vmatrix} 
x+n-1 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & \cdots & x+n-1 & x+n-1 \\
 n-1 & x+n-2 & x+n-1 & x+n-1 & \cdots &x+n-1 & x+n-1 \\ 
 0 & n-2 & x+n-3 &  x+n-1 & \cdots &  x+n-1 &  x+n-1 \\ 
 0 & 0 & n-3 & x+n-4 & \cdots &  x+n-1 &  x+n-1 \\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x+1 & x+n-1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x 
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
In this determinant the elements above the diagonal are all $x+n-1$．We successively subtract the $k$-th column from the $k+1$-th column, $k=n-1,n-2,\cdots,1$, and finally get
\begin{align*}
D_n(x)=
\begin{vmatrix} 
x+n-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 n-1 & x-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & n-2 & x-1 & 2 & \cdots &  0 &  0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & n-3 & x-1 & \cdots &  0 &  0 \\ 
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x-1 & n-2 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x-1
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
By expanding the above determinant along its first row, we obtain
\begin{align*}
D_n(x)=&(x+n-1)\begin{vmatrix}
 x-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
  n-2 & x-1 & 2 & \cdots &  0 &  0 \\ 
 0 & n-3 & x-1 & \cdots &  0 &  0 \\ 
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & x-1 & n-2 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & x-1
\end{vmatrix}\\
=&(x+n-1)D_{n-1}(x-1)
\end{align*}
Using the above recurrence relation, we can get
\begin{align*}
D_n(x)=&(x+n-1)(x+n-3)D_{n-2}(x-2)\\
=&(x+n-1)(x+n-3)\cdots (x+n+1-2k)D_{n-k}(x-k)\\
=&(x+n-1)(x+n-3)\cdots (x-n+3)D_{1}(x-n+1)\\
=&(x+n-1)(x+n-3)\cdots (x-n+3)(x-n+1)\\
=&\prod_{k=1}^{n}\big(x+n+1-2k\big)\\
=&\begin{cases}
(x^2-(n-1)^2)(x^2-(n-3)^2)\cdots (x^2-1^2),~~~\text{when $n$ is even}\\ 
(x^2-(n-1)^2)(x^2-(n-3)^2)\cdots (x^2-2^2)x,~\text{when $n$ is odd．}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice induction proof!

Answer (score 1):

We set $x=0$ and show that $A$ has eigenvalues $\pm(n-1),\pm(n-3),\ldots$ by finding a matrix that diagonalizes it. The solution of the problem follows easily from there.

Let $P$ be the [Pascal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix) defined by
$$p_{ij} = {{j-1}\choose{i-1}}  = \frac{(j-1)^{\underline{i-1}}}{(i-1)!}\,,$$
where we have used generalization of binomial coefficient, defined using [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).
For example, when $n=4$ we have
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\ 0&1&2&3\\ 0&0&1&2\\ 0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\,.$$
Let $S$ be diagonal matrix defined by
$$s_{ii} = 2^{n-i}{n-1\choose i-1}\,.$$
Then matrix $$V = P^{-1}SP^T$$ is such that $V^{-1}AV$ is diagonal, with eigenvalues sorted in descending order.

**Proof.** To prove this claim, let $L$ be the lower triangle and $U$ be the upper triangle of matrix $A$. Also, let $D$ be diagonal matrix defined by $d_{ii}=n+1-2i$, so that its diagonal elements are eigenvalues sorted in descending order.

We start with equivalence
$$V^{-1}AV=D \;\Leftrightarrow\; S^{-1}PAP^{-1}S = P^TDP^{-T}\,.$$

To simplify the last equality we will use the following three equalities
$$PUP^{-1}=U\,,\quad PLP^{-1}=D+L-U\,,\quad PDP^{-1}=D-2U\,.$$
One can prove them by multiplying them from the right by $P$ and by comparing the resulting left and right hand side, using properties of binomial coefficient.

We sum the first two equalities to obtain
$$PAP^{-1}=D+L\,.$$
We use the last and the first equality to obtain
$$D=P^{-1}DP-2P^{-1}UP = P^{-1}DP-2U\,.$$
Adding $2U$ to the both sides of this equality and transposing gives
$$P^TDP^{-T}=D+2U^T\,.$$

Now, we have
$$V^{-1}AV=D \;\Leftrightarrow\; S^{-1}(D+L)S=D+2U^T \;\Leftrightarrow\; S^{-1}LS=2U^T \,.$$
The last equation can be seen to hold by multiplying it from the left by $S$ and comparing the resulting left and right hand side. This ends the proof.

The idea for solution came from the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196991/finding-the-determinant-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix).

Comment: Thanks for your reply,it's not easy to think of constructing such a matrix $P$,I will read it carefully.By the way,below I have posted a solution to this question,which needs some tricks of determinant.