# A Hermitian Matrix $H$ acting on $|0\rangle, \cdots, |N \rangle$,entries $\langle j+1 |H |j \rangle= \langle j| H | j+1 \rangle = \sqrt{(N-j)(j+1)}/2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N$ be a positive integer. Consider a Hamiltonian (a Hermitian matrix) acting on orthogonal basis states $|0 \rangle, \cdots, |N \rangle$ (Dirac notation), for which the non-zero matrix entries are $\langle j+1 |H |j \rangle= \langle j| H | j+1 \rangle = \sqrt{(N-j)(j+1)}/2$. A paper I am reading states without proof that

i) $e^{-i \pi H}|0 \rangle = |N \rangle$

ii) $||H ||  = N/2$ (not sure which matrix norm is being used, although it could possibly be the trace norm)

I am focused mostly on trying to understand i) for now. In the case where $N=1$, then $H$ is a matrix of dimension $2 \times 2$ of the form : 
$H = \frac {1} {\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end {bmatrix}$, where $H^k = \begin{cases}  \frac {1} {\sqrt{2}}^k\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end {bmatrix} \text{if $k \mod 2 = 1$}  \\ \frac {1} {\sqrt{2}}^k I_{2\times 2} \text{   if $k \mod 2 = 0$}\end{cases}$.

Expanding $e^{-i \pi H} = I  -i \pi H  - \pi^2 \frac {1}{4}I + \cdots$

I'm not sure how to continue more generally for any $N$ and how to conclude $i)$. Insights appreciated.

Comment: As far as i) goes I would consider writing down an eigenbasis and find out what the inner product equations you have in the given basis look like in the eigenbasis. Then I would write the exponential as the exponential of a diagonalized matrix and see if I could get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first claim isn't quite right. The correct statement should be $e^{-i\pi H}|0\rangle=(-i)^N|N\rangle$.

In view of user [Yukinooo's question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3280815), I believe there is a simple physics-oriented proof of the statement. Anyway, here is a matrix-theoretic proof. For $j=1,2,\ldots,N$, let $h_j=\sqrt{(N+1-j)j\,}$. Then
$$
H=\frac12\pmatrix{0&h_1\\ h_1&0&h_2\\ &h_2&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&0&h_N\\ &&&h_N&0}.
$$
It is known that $2H$ is [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281284) to the [Kac matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340611)
$$
K=\pmatrix{0&1\\ N&0&2\\ &N-1&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&0&N\\ &&&1&0}
$$
via the similarity transform $2H=D^{-1}KD$ where
$$
D=\operatorname{diag}(d_0,\ldots,d_N),\ d_k = \frac1{k!}\prod_{i=1}^k h_i.
$$
$K$ can be diagonalised as $K=V\Lambda V^{-1}$ where
$$
\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}\left(N,\,N-2,\,N-4,\ldots,\,-(N-4),\,-(N-2),\,-N\right)
$$
and $V$ is the zero-indexed [Krawtchouk matrix](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F0-387-23394-6_5)
$$
V_{ij} = \sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k\binom{j}{k}\binom{N-j}{i-k}
$$
with the property that $V^2=2^NI$. One may verify that $SV|0\rangle=V|N\rangle$ where
$$
S=\operatorname{diag}\left(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,(-1)^N\right).
$$
Thus
\begin{aligned}
e^{-i\pi H}|0\rangle
&=D^{-1}\exp(-i\pi K/2)D|0\rangle\\
&=D^{-1}\exp(-i\pi K/2)|0\rangle\ \text{(because $d_0=1$)}\\
&=D^{-1}V\exp(-i\pi \Lambda/2)V^{-1}|0\rangle\\
&=D^{-1}V\left((-i)^NS\right)V^{-1}|0\rangle\\
&=(-i)^ND^{-1}VSV^{-1}|0\rangle\\
&=(-i)^ND^{-1}V^{-1}SV|0\rangle\ \text{(because $V^2=2^NI$)}\\
&=(-i)^ND^{-1}V^{-1}V|N\rangle\ \text{(because $SV|0\rangle=V|N\rangle$)}\\
&=(-i)^ND^{-1}|N\rangle\\
&=(-i)^N|N\rangle\ \text{(because $d_N=1$)}.
\end{aligned}
Moreover, since $H$ is similar to $K/2$, its largest-sized eigenvalues are $\pm N/2$. Therefore (as $H$ is real symmetric) its spectral norm is $\|H\|_2=\rho(H)=N/2$.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea how complicated of a problem this was. Thanks a lot for the help, there is no way I would have come up with that myself.  I will be studying this tomorrow to understand more clearly.