How do I compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix?
Coming from a problem on the Putnam, the problem hinged on finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac1{n} & \frac1{n} & 0 & 0&\ldots & 0 \\
    \frac{n-1}{n} & \frac1{n} & \frac2{n} & 0 &\ldots & 0\\
    0 & \frac{n-2}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \frac3{n} & \ldots & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots& \ddots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 &\ldots & \frac2{n} &\frac1{n} & \frac{n-1}{n}\\
    0 & 0 &\ldots & 0 &  \frac1{n} & \frac1{n}
  \end{bmatrix}
Is there a good way to compute this?

It is a linear combination of the Kac matrix and the identity matrix. To find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, see https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(91)90179-Z . See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340611 for a quick derivation of the eigenvalues of the Kac matrix.

Wow, so I was not gonna get that question haha
